# Does access to legal marijuana reduce dependence on opiates and other drugs?

Tags: recreational-drugs, epidemiology, marijuana, pharmaceutical

It has recently been reported in several news sources that places where access to marijuana has been legalised have seen significant decreases in the use of other, more dangerous, drugs.

In an article arguing that a more relaxed approach to medical marajuana could save the US government a large amount of money, [Forbes reports](https://www.forbes.com/sites/janetwburns/2017/02/26/paging-dr-spicer-cannabis-could-help-fight-opioid-abuse-and-save-us-billions-actually/#351c707a292c), for example:

> ...states with legalized medicinal marijuana laws saw significant drops in prescriptions for pain medication, as well as for antidepressants, seizure medication, anxiety medication, sleep aids, and anti-nausea drugs, among others.

Given the normal governmental attitude to recreational pharmaceuticals, this seems likely to be controversial. Is it true that access to marijuana can reduce the use of other drugs significantly?

Comment: This question is undoubtedly related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35817/in-states-where-marijuana-is-legal-did-prescription-painkiller-sales-decrease

Comment: @JDoe You are right, though this one is broader. I missed the other question when I searched (possibly because I looked for marijuana *and* opiates.) The issue is about both legal and illegal drug use here and the other question is prescribed only.

Comment: I agree your question is different, but I think the source for your referenced claim is in an answer to the linked question. Sorry I don't have the time to write you the kind of thought-out answer you deserve.